# System.out.println(super) in java

Tags: java, this, super

`this` in java works as a reference variable, but `super` does not, why?
Example:
we can do `System.out.println("this: " + this);`
but we can never do  `System.out.println("Super: " + super);`

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        System.out.println("Base Constructor");
    }
}

class Child extends Base
{
    public Child()
    {
        System.out.println("Child Constructor");
        System.out.println("this: " + this);
        //System.out.println("Super: " + super);
    }
}
```

The reason I think of is, when we use `new` keyword then a memory is allocated in heap and the reference ID of that memory is saved in `this`. But there no memory space allocation for parent in heap so there no reference ID to be stored in `super`.

Am I Wrong? Or is there anything am missing with. So can we say `this` is a reference variable & `super` is not?

Comment: *super* is not an object of its own. trying to access *super* is like trying to peal out the *mammal* from a *human*...

Comment: that's what am saying. `this is a reference variable` & `super is not``

Comment: "But there no memory space allocation for parent in heap" while this is true because `new` creates only single object (or class pointed by constructor), purpose of `super` is not to return instance of parent class (since there is none) but just allows class to use members from parent class. For instance if class overrides some method it still can invoke code from "original" method from parent class.

Comment: For example in swing application when we extend component and want to draw on it we need to override `paintComponent` method. But before we will draw *our* additional graphics we want to draw standard graphics first (like default borders, background) and then draw on that. So we call `super.paintComponent(g)` at start of overridden method.

Answer (score 4):

The `super` keyword in Java is not an object reference, **unlike** `this`. `this` is used as a reference to the calling object. However super is a keyword that is used to resolve the parent class' methods and data members. `super` points to the parent class. But, `this` points to the calling object.

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

This is why you CAN print an object. But you cannot print `super`.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the compiler will store the `this` to local variable table at slot 0.

See the following code:

```
public void t(){
    System.out.println(this);
}
```

and the byte code is:

```
 public void t();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: aload_0
     4: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
     7: return
  LineNumberTable:
    line 81: 0
    line 82: 7
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0       8     0  this   Lcom/zhuyiren/Main;
```

And in the `JVMS 2.6.1 Local Variables`,there is some explanation:

**On instance method invocation,local variable 0 is always used to pass a reference to the object on which the instance method is being invoked (this in the Java programming language)**

Comment: You should maybe link more info on "local variable table".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. There's no reference ID which can be stored in `super`, so that's why we can't print it. `super` is just a keyword which is used to access parent data members/constructor.